# Use of notation => in a subclass

Tags: c#, .net, overriding, subclass, notation

What does the following mean when written in a subclass:

```
public override bool IsReadOnly
    => false;
```

Does this differ from:

```
public override bool IsReadonly
{
  get 
  {
    return false;
  }
}
```

Comment: No; this is a new syntatic sugar in C# 6.

Comment: Sorry I misunderstood what you mean when you say No; Are the two statements equivalent or is there a subtle difference?

Comment: @SLaks what is the name of this sugar?

Comment: @steve_cdi No, there is no difference between the two.

Comment: This is an _expression-bodied member_.

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn802602.aspx

Comment: "syntactic sugar" means better (more "sugary" syntax) that does the same thing.

Comment: Thank you SLaks, very quick response and much appreciated. My first question so I'm unfamiliar with the rewards system, but I understand that I can't mark a comment as an answer. I will mark Arturo's answer below if that's OK.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What does the following mean when written in a subclass

This is a new feature in *C# 6.0* called **Expression Body**, this is a syntactic sugar that allows define getter-only properties and indexers where the body of the getter is given by the expression body.

> Does this differ from

No, there is no difference between this and the classic form, is just an syntactic sugar.

Methods as well can be defined as an expression-bodied:

```
public void PrintLine(string line) => Console.WriteLine(line);
```

Answer (score 1):

Its the same thing, there is no difference, like our friend Slaks said, its just syntactic sugar. "=>" is the lambda expression of assignment.